# what jquery plugin styles form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

whats the best jquery plugin to style form controls?

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quite like [jQuery Uniform](http://Uniformjs.com): but this only styles normally not stylable elements (select boxes, for instance), so you will still need CSS styling for the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Formalize](http://formalize.me/) came out recently, I really like it, used it a few times already.

Comment: that looks just like what I was looking for.  Are there any tutorials on it?

Comment: Theres the [blog post](http://sonspring.com/journal/formalize-css) on it. And a [demo page](http://formalize.me/demo.html) but that seems to be it from the official site. Some googling might reveal 3rd party tutorials.